# How to find current time of a region from a old time string in php?

Tags: php, time

I am getting time string from some mails `date` header. I need to get how much second before the mail has been sent to user.

Here is my code that I am trying to solve the problem.

```
<?php
//time string found in mail date header
$time_string = 'Wed, 15 Nov 2017 14:50:53 -0800 (PST)';

//when i use 'D, j M Y G:i:s O (e)' as identifier then date_create_from_format returns false
$mail_date = explode(" ", $time_string);
unset($mail_date[6]);
$dt_in = date_create_from_format('D, j M Y G:i:s O', implode(" ", $mail_date));
$time_in = strtotime(date_format($dt_in, 'd-m-Y H:i:s')) ; // This time may be according to my time zone (that is wrong need according to that time zone '-0800')

//returns time zone that is not compatible with php
$time_zone = date_format($dt_in, 'T'); //returns GMT-0800

//rest of the code not working
date_default_timezone_set($time_zone); //date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'GMT-0800' is invalid
$difference = time()-$time_in;
print_r($difference);
?>
```

It is not impotent to correct this code or do it like this. All I need to get the time difference. Any solution will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: I sense a possible [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: It is part of my project.

Comment: I can show you my full code if you want

Answer (score 0):

Convert date from email to a timestamp and compare with the current timestamp:

```
$time_string = 'Wed, 15 Nov 2017 14:50:53 -0800 (PST)';
$mail_date = explode(" ", $time_string);
unset($mail_date[6]);
$mail_datetime = date_create_from_format('D, j M Y G:i:s O', implode(" ", $mail_date));
$time_diff_in_seconds = time() - $mail_datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: my `date_default_timezone` is different and also zone(eg. -0800) may vary. so `$time_diff_in_seconds` is wrong here.

Comment: I've fixed the code. The basic principle here is comparing dates in the unix timestamp format.

Comment: my zone is +0600 in my php so here time difference in second will be according to my (+0600) zone. but i need according to -0800 or whatever declared in string

Comment: actually here is the problem

Comment: Unix time do not change accross timezones. It is a system for describing a point in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).